# C# GetHostEntry IPV6

Tags: c#, server, client, ipv6

I am trying to build a client/server program to transmit results of certain equations based on client input. I can get it to work no issue using 127.0.0.1, however since I am wanting to send this to clients I cannot use that. Not all clients will be on the LAN and will be transmitting over WAN. Here is a snippit of my code

```
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

I have tried using the external IPV4 address but am not even able to ping it, I can, however ping the IPV6 address and would rather use that. However when I throw in my IPV4 address the program is simply unable to connect. Any advice?

EDIT
Okay, So I have managed to connect them over two different LAN computers, however after sending one or two times the LAN client gives me this

> Socket Connected to 192.168.1.6:11000
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0X80004005): A request to send or
>   receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and
>   (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was
>   supplied  At System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginSend(Byte[] buffer, int32
>   offset, int32 size, Socket Flags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback,
>   object state)  at ConsoleApp1.Form1.Send(Socket Client, String data)
>   In (FileLocation) Line 111  at ConsoleApp1.Foorm1.button1_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in (FileLocation) Line 177

Comment: Are you on a server with direct internet connection or behind a NAT-router?

Comment: I am behind a NAT router with port forwarding setup to the server computer. In reality I would prefer to be able to set it up to accept either IPV6 or IPV4, just due to some clients may not have an IPV6 address. If you need further code feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen on all addresses to overcome this problem by using `IPAddress.Any`:

```
// Create a TCP/IP socket.  
var client = new Socket(IPAddress.Any.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000));
```

Comment: This is actually going from client to server, I have the server (I believe) setup properly.

Comment: @mpotts Hmm, then I don't completely understand the question: What information from the server do you have? DNS name, IPv4 address?

Comment: Here is the code from the server.

      IPHostEntry ipHostInfo =dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
      IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
      IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

The code in the original post was the connection from client to server.

Comment: @mpotts I mean what does the client know about the server?

Comment: My apologies, I've tried just typing in the IPV6 address, no response. I've tried my IPV4 local, same thing. Tried public IPV4 and likewise. 127.0.0.1 was the only address that would take. I did end up making a change server side and am currently deploying a VM to test on the LAN

Comment: I'm actually running into a new issue,I've notated it in the main post

Comment: @mpotts Can you show us the complete code (creation, connection and using of the sockets) on the client and the server? (please update the question again)